# How to access the AVAudioPlayer in all the viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

This is what i have in mind. A `TableViewController`. When i tap on one of the cells, another `viewcontroller` is presented that contains instances of `AVAudioPlayer` and have a seek bar and stop and pause button. Then when i close the player viewcontroller, the music plays on and is not stopped (i have successfully completed the whole thing untill here). Now i wanna create a "Now Playing" button. When i tap on it, it takes me back to the audio player ViewController and i can see the progress of the song. Any ideas on how to do this? My problem is that i do not know how to store the information of the song playing in the background and constantly update these information.

Comment: Create a class which contains the AVPlayer and plays the audio in your main view controller. It should have methods to queue items and stop, play or next. Make the same object delegate to AVPlayer and when the playerDidFinishPlaying: method triggers broadcast a notification saying that the player has finished. In the NSNotification make the object to the same object having playing. Then the receiver listening to this notification anywhere have access to the player object and can play next or stop or do all kinds of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with creating singleton class with class method that will return the instance of its AVAudioPlayer class. All the AVAudioPlayer operation should be manage on this singleton class. With this you can implement AVAudioPlayer with single object that will accessible in all view controller class with its current state. Method will be called as:

```
[[MyAVAudioPlayer getInstance] getStatus];
[[MyAVAudioPlayer getInstance] play];
```

Class structure can be as:

```
@interface MyAVAudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer{

}

+(MyAVAudioPlayer *)getInstance;
-(void)playWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
-(void)play;
-(float)status; 
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a singleton class with `AVAudioPlayer`. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086419/how-to-create-avplayer-singleton-class) here

Comment: Orite now the problem is that i dunno what singletons are. I need to read a lil bit about it. thanks anyway! would vote up if i had enough reps

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `NSNotification` you can add an observer to property to check and update your cell when this property change.